# Adding a method to class that inherits from an Interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is .NET 4.0/C#. I have a class that inherits from an interface:

```
public class DocumentModel : IDocumentObject
{
     //this is not in the interface and wont ever be
     public void NewMethod(){//my code}
}
```

In my `DocumentModel` class, I added a public method that is not a part of the interface. When I call it,

```
var doc = new DocumentModel();
doc.NewMethod();
```

I get the following:

> Error 30 'IDocumentObject' does not contain a definition for 'NewMethod' and no
>   extension method 'NewMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'IDocumentObject'

How do I add a method to my class that's not in the interface? Thanks

Comment: Could you rename your class method to something else? Interfaces enforce names when implemented on a class. If not, add an interface method description.

Comment: The code as posted should work fine.  There is something else going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interface add the method declaration.

```
public interface IDocumentObject
{
void NewMethod();
}
```

Or if you do not want it in the interface, you'll have to create an instance of the class of the type of the class, not the type of interface.

```
DocumentModel doc = new DocumentModel();
```

Comment: Thats what i was doing wrong. I created a new instance of my DocumentModel object and it works. Thanks

Comment: @user1202717 you never create an instance of an interface type. you declared it as an interface type through var. Its always an actual concrete type

Answer (score 4):

Use explicit type "DocumentModel" instead of `var`  while creating object of DocumentModel  class.

Comment: Could you explain reason for this?

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference.  Type inference should already be typing `doc` as a `DocumentModel` anyway, not `IDocumentObject`. EDIT: at least with the code posted; perhaps the actual code being used isn't as explicit as what was posted.

Comment: I'm agree with Chris. So waiting for explanations.

Comment: Plus, even if it was inferring IDocumentObject instead of DocumentModel, it wouldn't compile. Considering that DocumentModel, as shown here, doesn't inherit from anything else besides Object, there's really no reason for the var to infer anything besides DocumentModel.

Answer (score 0):

What Romil says might help, but the below code runs as is.  Explicitly declaring your type would help the compiler determine the right type.  Using `var` leaves the decision on the type of the variable compiler, and it might typing it as the interface, instead of the concrete class.  You could look at your output assembly in a disassembler like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and see what's actually going on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface iDoc
{

}

class doc : iDoc
{
    public void meth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("asdf");
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d = new doc();
        d.meth();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As a further example, if you explicitly declare the variable's type as the interface, you can still cast it back to its concrete type and call the method like below.

```
iDoc d = new doc();
((doc)d).meth();
```